# meta information does not show the installed transformer module

Tags: weaviate

I have installed version 1.2.1 of weaviate and selected a transformer module. but the /v1/meta endpoint does not display the transformer details. I get the following:

```
{
  "hostname": "http://[::]:8080",
  "modules": {
    "text2vec-transformers": {
      
    }
  },
  "version": "1.2.1"
}
```

Comment: The behavior you're describing is actually expected in 1.2.1. The presence of the `text2vec-transoformers` key under modules indicates that the module is present and running correctly. It does not currently provide any other meta info. However, in a future release, it will print info such as which transformers model is running, etc.

Comment: Hey @Gadhu, just wanted to update you that this is being addressed as part of Weaviate `v.1.3.0` where each transformers module now shows metadata about the underlying model.

Comment: Thanks @etiennedi. As we start switching transformers often, this will be very useful to check if I am using the right one.

Comment: @etiennedi Just verified on v.1.3.0 . Very clear now. Able to see details of the qna-transformers as well as text2vec transformers. Brilliant!!!